# How to run Visual Studio 2017 Package Manager commands through PowerShell or command line

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, nuget-package

How to run Visual Studio 2017 Package Manager commands through PowerShell or the command line?

I am using Visual studio 2017 for Entity Framework - Database migration, The following command is run on Package Manager console of Visual Studio:

1. Enable-Migrations - ContextTypeName Database.TemplateDbContext
2. add-migration InitialCreate
3. Update-Database - Script -SourceMigration: $InitialDatabase (To generate migration script)
4. Update-Database - Verbose (To update the database)

The above script is working fine, but now I'm working on automation of this database migration without using Visual Studio Package Manager. Is there any method to call these commands from either the command prompt or from PowerShell scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For migration from Command, you could try

For `add-migration InitialCreate`, you could try

`dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate`

For `Update-Database`, you could try

`dotnet ef database update`

Check [Migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/)

Comment: How do we handle the scaffolding, My scaffolding commands are:
    Install-Package MvcScaffolding , 
    Scaffold Controller ModelName

Comment: @GeorgeThomas Check [Scaffold the movie model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio-code#scaffold-the-movie-model)